# How can I find all of objects in a list of an object's child recursively?

Tags: c#, json, recursion

I have a object which I need to process. This object is of type `SchemaValidationResults` which contains a list `List<SchemaValidationResults> NestedResults` which may or may not contain further `SchemaValidationResults` objects.

To make this more clear I've provided a JSON representation below. Within this JSON  representation is a parent object, which contains a child object that has two children objects. One of these children objects has a further child object.

So we have:

```
Parent
     Child
          Child
          Child
               Child
```

I need to be able to retrieve the objects in this JSON represntation that do not have any further children. So in the above structure I need these two children.

```
Parent
     Child
          Child <-- Need
          Child
               Child <- Need
```

JSON

```
{
  "valid": false,
  "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties",
  "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections",
  "keyword": "properties",
  "errors": [
    {
      "valid": false,
      "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions",
      "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions",
      "errors": [
        {
          "valid": false,
          "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions/properties/102/$ref/properties/answer/type",
          "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions/102/answer",
          "keyword": "type",
          "additionalInfo": {
            "expected": "string",
            "actual": "number"
          }
        },
        {
          "valid": false,
          "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions/allOf",
          "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions",
          "keyword": "allOf",
          "errors": [
            {
              "valid": false,
              "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions/allOf/0/else/properties/100/properties/answer/maxLength",
              "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions/100/answer",
              "keyword": "maxLength",
              "additionalInfo": {
                "expected": 0,
                "actual": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The nature of this leads me to believe that recursion will be able to help me create a list of all the children objects that do not have further children.

However I started to write a method and I quickly realised that I'm unsure as to how I should structure the method to achieve the result that I want. So far I have this:

```
public List<SchemaValidationResults> GetChildLessError(SchemaValidationResults errors)
        {
            List<SchemaValidationResults> childLessErrors = new List<SchemaValidationResults>();

            foreach(var result in errors.NestedResults)
            {
                if(result.NestedResults.Count == 0)
                {
                    childLessErrors.Add(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(var resultChild in result.NestedResults)
                    childLessErrors.AddRange(GetChildLessError(resultChild));
                }
            }

            return childLessErrors;
        }
```

This method kind of works, it produces a list of objects that do not have any children, however out of the 10 I was expecting it only produces 6 objects.

Below is the full JSON file I am running this method on. The first JSON file was just a snippet.

```
{
  "valid": false,
  "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties",
  "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections",
  "keyword": "properties",
  "errors": [
    {
      "valid": false,
      "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/1/properties/questions/properties/3/$ref/properties/answer/enum",
      "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/1/questions/3/answer",
      "keyword": "enum"
    },
    {
      "valid": false,
      "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions",
      "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions",
      "errors": [
        {
          "valid": false,
          "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions/properties/102/$ref/properties/answer/type",
          "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions/102/answer",
          "keyword": "type",
          "additionalInfo": {
            "expected": "string",
            "actual": "number"
          }
        },
        {
          "valid": false,
          "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions/allOf",
          "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions",
          "keyword": "allOf",
          "errors": [
            {
              "valid": false,
              "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions/allOf/0/else/properties/100/properties/answer/maxLength",
              "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions/100/answer",
              "keyword": "maxLength",
              "additionalInfo": {
                "expected": 0,
                "actual": 2
              }
            },
            {
              "valid": false,
              "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions/allOf/1/else/properties/101/properties/answer/maxLength",
              "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions/101/answer",
              "keyword": "maxLength",
              "additionalInfo": {
                "expected": 0,
                "actual": 3
              }
            },
            {
              "valid": false,
              "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/6/properties/questions/allOf/4/else/properties/104/properties/answer/maxLength",
              "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/6/questions/104/answer",
              "keyword": "maxLength",
              "additionalInfo": {
                "expected": 0,
                "actual": 5
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "valid": false,
      "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/8/properties/questions",
      "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/8/questions",
      "errors": [
        {
          "valid": false,
          "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/8/properties/questions/properties/191/$ref/properties/answer",
          "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/8/questions/191/answer",
          "errors": [
            {
              "valid": false,
              "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/8/properties/questions/properties/191/$ref/properties/answer/minLength",
              "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/8/questions/191/answer",
              "keyword": "minLength",
              "additionalInfo": {
                "expected": 1,
                "actual": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "valid": false,
              "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/8/properties/questions/properties/191/$ref/properties/answer/enum",
              "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/8/questions/191/answer",
              "keyword": "enum"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "valid": false,
          "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/8/properties/questions/allOf/12/else/properties/191/properties/answer/enum",
          "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/8/questions/191/answer",
          "keyword": "enum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "valid": false,
      "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/9/properties/questions/allOf",
      "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/9/questions",
      "keyword": "allOf",
      "errors": [
        {
          "valid": false,
          "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/9/properties/questions/allOf/0/else/properties/211/properties/answer/maxLength",
          "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/9/questions/211/answer",
          "keyword": "maxLength",
          "additionalInfo": {
            "expected": 0,
            "actual": 12
          }
        },
        {
          "valid": false,
          "keywordLocation": "#/properties/form_submission/properties/sections/properties/9/properties/questions/allOf/1/else/properties/240/properties/answer/maxLength",
          "instanceLocation": "#/form_submission/sections/9/questions/240/answer",
          "keyword": "maxLength",
          "additionalInfo": {
            "expected": 0,
            "actual": 4
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The answer lies within the question's title: How can I find all of objects in a list of an object's child? Recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one loop too many.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```
public List<SchemaValidationResults> GetChildLessError(SchemaValidationResults errors)
{
    List<SchemaValidationResults> childLessErrors = new List<SchemaValidationResults>();

    if(errors.NestedResults.Any())
    {
        foreach(var resultChild in errors.NestedResults)
        {
            childLessErrors.AddRange(GetChildLessError(resultChild));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        childLessErrors.Add(errors);                    
    }
    return childLessErrors;
}
```